# How to add cron job schedule in server by php function in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want a php function for wordpress which added the cron jobs schedule on server.
Any one know about it???

```
wp_schedule_event();
```

Is not working offline condition. So i think server cron job is better way for me.

Comment: there is no `function` in wordpress to create a cronjob per-say.  you have to set up cron jobs on the server, through C-Panel, or crontab -via- the command line.

Comment: Thanks buddy @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: Please see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event for the wordpress function. `The action will trigger when someone visits your WordPress site, if the scheduled time has passed`

Comment: Is there any way in wordpress which auto run some php file with custom plugin??

Comment: No, wordpress can only run the scheduled task if someone visits your page.  You can run wordpress via the command line, and turn some things off ...

Comment: google  WP-CLI for information on wordpress's command line interface.

Comment: Thanks again brother for giving me that solution.. @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: Sure, thanks for being Kind ... lol